# Is $scope.$$phase future-proof?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Currently I'm using $scope.$$phase to avoid the `Error: $digest already in progress` problem, but I am concerned whether it will be likely to break in future. Since it is prefixed with "$$", in my understanding this is internal state of angularjs, it shouldn't be used by user code and its behavior may change on anytime (please correct me if I was wrong). But I can't find other good workaround to this problem so I am forced to use this, but I feel a bit uncomfortable using something with uncertain future.

My question is that, is there any policy on API stability of $$-prefixed scope variables (or specifically $$phase)? I digged through the official documentation and searched around but couldn't find much information about this.

Comment: I guess only the angularjs dev can give you an accurate answer. What I can tell you is that we used to rely heavily on `$$phase` in order to avoid this kind of error, and we have come to realize that it was never is really necessary as long as you stick to a simple rule: calls that come from "outside" are encapsulated in `scope.$apply()` and the rest isn't.

Comment: I know I should only use `$apply` in native event handler, but in my project, several event handlers sometimes triggers another DOM event inside `$apply`, so the target handler can't be sure whether the call is from inside or outside, and needs workaround like checking `$$phase`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nobody can guarantee that it's not going to change in the future, but taking into account the way current angular.js source looks like, it seems rather unlikely.

Anyway, it's better to wrap scripts using $scope.$$phase and $scope.$apply() in a single, reusable service, so in the future you would have to replace one dependency instead of hundreds of files.

[$scope.safeApply()](https://github.com/yearofmoo/AngularJS-Scope.SafeApply) is a decent example if you don't want to reinvent the wheel:)

Comment: I have been using this approach, although a bit different from the one in your link. Thanks anyway. :)